# postgresql in docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run the code from the below link.

https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/tree/master/11/alpine

But jenkins build is failing, i have pasted the error message from jenkins below.  please help me to git rid of this error.

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  .build-deps-0:
    masked in: cache
    satisfies: world[.build-deps]
  perl-utils (missing):
    required by:
  perl-ipc-run (missing):
    required by:
The command '/bin/sh -c set -ex         && apk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch-deps         ca-certificates         openssl         tar         && wget -O postgresql.tar.bz2 "https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v$PG_VERSION/postgresql-$PG_VERSION.tar.bz2"     && echo "$PG_SHA256 *postgresql.tar.bz2" | sha256sum -c -     && mkdir -p /usr/src/postgresql     && tar         --extract         --file postgresql.tar.bz2         --directory /usr/src/postgresql         --strip-components 1     && rm postgresql.tar.bz2         && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps         bison         coreutils         dpkg-dev dpkg         flex         gcc         libc-dev         libedit-dev         libxml2-dev         libxslt-dev         make         openssl-dev         perl-utils         perl-ipc-run         util-linux-dev         zlib-dev         icu-dev         && cd /usr/src/postgresql     && awk '$1 == "#define" && $2 == "DEFAULT_PGSOCKET_DIR" && $3 == "\"/tmp\"" { $3 = "\"/var/run/postgresql\""; print; next } { print }' src/include/pg_config_manual.h > src/include/pg_config_manual.h.new     && grep '/var/run/postgresql' src/include/pg_config_manual.h.new     && mv src/include/pg_config_manual.h.new src/include/pg_config_manual.h     && gnuArch="$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)"     && wget -O config/config.guess 'https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/config.git/plain/config.guess?id=7d3d27baf8107b630586c962c057e22149653deb'     && wget -O config/config.sub 'https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/config.git/plain/config.sub?id=7d3d27baf8107b630586c962c057e22149653deb'     && ./configure         --build="$gnuArch"         --enable-integer-datetimes         --enable-thread-safety         --enable-tap-tests         --disable-rpath         --with-uuid=e2fs         --with-gnu-ld         --with-pgport=5432         --with-system-tzdata=/usr/share/zoneinfo         --prefix=/usr/local         --with-includes=/usr/local/include         --with-libraries=/usr/local/lib                 --with-openssl         --with-libxml         --with-libxslt         --with-icu     && make -j "$(nproc)" world     && make install-world     && make -C contrib install         && runDeps="$(         scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local             | tr ',' '\n'             | sort -u             | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }'     )"     && apk add --no-cache --virtual .postgresql-rundeps         $runDeps         bash         su-exec         tzdata     && apk del .fetch-deps .build-deps     && cd /     && rm -rf         /usr/src/postgresql         /usr/local/share/doc         /usr/local/share/man     && find /usr/local -name '*.a' -delete' returned a non-zero code: 3
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a docker issue, but a shell issue. Also, it's a good demonstration as to why trying to shoehorn an entire bash script into a single line is a bad idea. One of those chained commands is failing, but figuring out which one is going to be a scavenger hunt. I would recommend refactoring this mega-oneliner into an actual proper bash script, then running it again and seeing what happens. This isn't on you, of course, but just a shitty design flaw in Docker that has an equally shitty workaround.

Comment: I have try it in my windows and it worked. At least doing a _docker build -t somename ._